# got unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' error when running on mac

Tags: bash

```
run_cmd="spark-submit \
$SPARK_OPTIONS \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.default.name=file:/// \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS=file:/// \
--py-files \
${TARGET}/test.zip \
$TEST_PY \
$RAW_DATA_FILE \
$OUTPUT \
--route $AGG_OUTPUT1 \
--origin $AGG_OUTPUT2 \
--first $AGG_OUTPUT3" #line 71

echo $run_cmd
echo $run_cmd | bash 
#line 75
```

The code is like above, it can run successfully on Ubuntu. However, when I run it on my macbook, the `spark-submit` finishes normally and output is also generated correctly, but then it outputs an error, it really sounds unreasonable. Also, if `spark-submit` exited abnormally, it won't trigger this error.

```
./test.sh: line 71: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./test.sh: line 75: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: What does [**ShellCheck.net**](http://www.shellcheck.net/) tell you?

Comment: @Cyrus it didn't report any error, actually it can run successful on our server, but not on my local macbook.

Comment: it reports some warning: Line 72:
echo $run_cmd
     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
 
Line 73:
echo $run_cmd | bash
     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Comment: You are most likely pulling in text that also contains literal quotes that can be causing  your problem. Is this a long variable in a `Makefile`?

Comment: could it be caused by line ending `\n` or `\r`?

Comment: Post your complete script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted all the relevant code, only some lines near 60~75.
The error you are getting happens when you have an unclosed `"` somewhere before the posted code. For example:

```
a="

b="something"
```

If you run this script with `bash`, it will report:

```
script.sh: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
script.sh: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

As in your case, the error is reported not on the line that didn't close the `"`,
but somewhere else.
What happens, Bash interprets the value of `a` as `\n\nb=`,
and then there is an opening `"` after `something` that's never closed.

The same thing is happening in your code.
Look for a `"` that isn't properly closed earlier in your script.

Comment: sorry guys, I know this sounds not real but I just cannot recreate this issue after accidentally reboot my computer.